# Checking if a file is signed using a Powershell script on Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, signing

I've written a simple Powershell script that throws an error if a file isn't signed:

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
$fileSignature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath <file that I want to check>
if ($fileSignature.Status -eq "NotSigned")
{
    throw "File is unsigned"
}
```

This works perfectly on Windows, but I need to port the script to run on Linux instead. I can still use Powershell there, but Get-AuthenticodeSignature hasn't been implemented for Linux yet. Are there any alternatives that I could use to perform the same test?